# Deriving Approximate Confidence Interval Using CLT

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, central-limit-theorem

I'd like to use the central limit theorem that (for large enough n), the random variable $$ Z = \sqrt{n} \left({\bar X \over \mu} -1\right) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$ and derive an approximate 100(1- $\alpha$)% confidence interval for $\mu$ when $n$ is large.

I see the relationship between the CLT, the normal distribution and the 100(1- $\alpha$)% interval: the CLT tells us that for the random variable above if there's a large enough $n$, we can get a p.d.f out of it. Also if we were to find the area under this curve, it'd give us some $1 -\alpha$

I'm not sure where I'd start in "showing" this is true and then deriving this confidence interval for $\mu$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt n (X_n- \mu)/\sigma$?

Comment: Anyway the standard route is $1-\alpha = P(-z_a < Z < z_a) = P(b < \mu < c)$ where $z_a$ is the point with $\alpha/2$ area on his right in the normal, and you find $b$ and $c$ substituting $Z = \sqrt{n} \left({\bar X \over \mu} -1\right) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and doing elementary algebra on both sides of the inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( Z_{a/2} \le \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu)}{\sigma} \le Z_{1-a/2}  \right)  = 1-a.
$$

Hence, an approximate CI for finite $n$ is 
$$
\left( \bar{X} - Z_{1-a/2}\frac{\sigma}{n}\le \mu \le \bar{X} + Z_{1-a/2}\frac{\sigma}{n}\right)
$$